# Flash CS6 Test Movie terminated automatically at random time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a project in Flash CS6 Air for Android, in this application I have to  send and receive data to server so I need an interval for update the data. I set an interval to 1000 milliseconds . The main problem is that my application is closing automatically at a random times.  I don't have to much for and while loops, because I was thinking at this first time. I don't receive any errors, the only message is

```
[UnloadSWF] App-Name.swf and Test Movie terminated.
```

I publish on android device and it works fine without closing. this is happening only on PC.
p.s. I am coding on the timeline.
thank you !

Comment: this is vary hard to attend cause we dont know much about your application, im guessing here its got to do with other factors at play..i could suggest to strip your application and run code blocks and see if this issue persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem. So when you run an application made in Adobe Air, there is open an Simulator with touch, accelerometer etc. (I use CS6) , if I close the simulator, the application close after few seconds(randomlly). If I don't close SIMULATOR it works without problems... hope this helps the guys who had the same problem. Sorry my bad english :)